# C# TCP connect, client cannot send message to server

Tags: c#, tcp, client-server

Why I cannot send message to server, can anyone help me? programming language is C#, I have turned off my firewall but it's still not work.

Why I cannot send message to server, can anyone help me? programming language is C#, I have turned off my firewall but it's still not work.

Here is my server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SimpleTCP;

namespace TCP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SimpleTcpServer server;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimiter = 0x13;
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                e.ReplyLine(string.Format("You said: {0}", e.MessageString));
            });
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text += "Server starting...";
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);
            server = new SimpleTcpServer().Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
            txtStatus.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Server connected!";
            //server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (server.IsStarted)
                server.Stop();
        }      
    }
}
```

Here is my client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SimpleTCP;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        SimpleTcpClient client;
 
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            //Connect to server
            client.Connect(txtHost.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
        }
 
        private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            //Update message to txtStatus
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;               
            });
        }
 
        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.WriteLineAndGetReply(txtMessage.Text, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I have problem with connection or message problem

Comment: The server and client cannot use the same IP address.  Make server listen to IPAddress.Any instead of the machine IP address.

Comment: but in the youtube tutorial, server and client both connect to 127.0.0.1 (port 8910)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve2LX1tOwIM

Comment: You tube on client never uses the IP address in the client code.